# MSSQL - Unable to find index entry in index ID 1

Tags: index, dbcc

Currently keep getting this severity 21 error through for a database that is hosted on SQL 2014 Enterprise with SP3 CU1 applied:

> DESCRIPTION:  Unable to find index entry in index ID 1, of table 2130106629, in database 'DatabaseName'. The indicated index is corrupt or there is a problem with the current update plan. Run DBCC CHECKDB or DBCC CHECKTABLE. If the problem persists, contact product support.

I've run the following to get the table name that is associated with the number:

```
select object_name(2130106629)
```

This then gives me the table name within the database. Looking at the table, there is only 2 rows of data and only one index, which is clustered on this table. I have done the DBCC checks for DB and table and these both come back clear.

I've also tried dropping the clustered index, but the error still comes through as:

> DESCRIPTION: Unable to find index entry in index ID **0**, of table 2130106629, in database 'DatabaseName'. The indicated index is corrupt or there is a problem with the current update plan. Run DBCC CHECKDB or DBCC CHECKTABLE. If the problem persists, contact product support.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to try next? Any ideas?